# Successive Squares in Python

Tags: python, math

I am writing a program in python that involves raising a number to an extremely high exponent. To do this, I am trying to implement the successive squares method to lower calculation time and remove the risk of overflow error.

Successive squares is meant to do the same thing as `base**exponent % modulo` and the current function I have written is this:

```
def ssp(b, m, n):
    ssp = 1
    while n>0:
        if n % 2 == 1:
            ssp = b*ssp % m
        b = b**2 % m
        n = n // 2
    return ssp
```

When I test the function with `ssp(7, 13, 93)` I get an answer of 8, when it should be 19. Can someone give a hint to what I did wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is with your function, but have you considered using the builtin `pow`?  It does the same thing.  http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#pow

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that the builtin `pow` is not at least as efficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing `pow(7, 93, 13)` => `8` but what you want is `pow(7, 13, 93)` => `19`

Swap your function's second and third argument.

```
>>> def ssp(b, n, m):
...     ssp = 1
...     while n>0:
...         if n % 2 == 1:
...             ssp = b*ssp % m
...         b = b**2 % m
...         n = n // 2
...     return ssp
... 
>>> ssp(7, 13, 93)
19
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I actually converted this from my MATLAB code so I was a bit sketchy on which variable was what in the end :P

Answer (score 1):

I think you just got the order of the arguments wrong. The 3rd argument is the exponent; the second is the modulus. That's probably not what you wanted.